# pip install selenium is throwing error " ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement selenium (from versions: none)"

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I have installed python 3.9.1 in my system. When i try to execute `pip install selenium` its throwing me error

**ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement selenium (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for selenium**

I have set environment variables correctly in path.

Is this issue occur due to any firewall or something.

[image]

Comment: Please try `python -m pip install selenium` instead of `pip install selenium`.

Comment: @Arty I am getting same error using mentioned command

Comment: It seems like the machine isn't connected to the internet. Or at least it can't connect to the Python Package Index. can you run a quick test and ping 8.8.8.8 or 'curl https://pypi.org/ '

Comment: No connection to https://pypi.org can be made. Can you open that URL in your browser? Can you ping the host?